# I want to run my server in nodemon but I get an error

Tags: javascript, express, schema

But I get an error saying this module.export is not a function in git bash
I will add more information about the problem if needed

```
//Schema code

const Mongoose = require("mongoose");

const users = new Mongoose.Schema(

{fName:{type:String, required:true},favFoode:String,age:Number});

const user1 = Mongoose.model("user",users)

module.exports(user1)

//Server code

const express = require("express");

const app = express()

require("./db")

require("./module/users")

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(200, ()=>{

console.log("This server is working");

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should assign the user1 variable to module.exports, like this:

```
module.exports = user1
```

Here is more information about Node.js modules: [Node.js API Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

Comment: Thanks for helping me the code worked I will look at the information you sent for reference